# DEPRECATION WARNING: update is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1 (please, use update instead) (called from block in set_order_id at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deprecated

I'm using Ruby version 2.5 and Rails version 6.0.2.2 and get this weird deprecation warning:

DEPRECATION WARNING: update is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1 (please, use update instead)

So "update" is deprecated and should be replaced with "update"?

Can anyone shine a light on this?

Comment: Seems strange - they _did_ deprecate `update_attributes` from Rails 5 to 6 though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Ruby on Rails public repository, this issue has been fixed in the next stable updates (6-0-stable-branch). Update your rails version using bundle. It'll be fixed automatically!

Comment: Yes, thanks Narendran. The upgrade seems to fixed the issue.